# Get Accurate Speed Readings From GDK

Tags: google-glass

I'm trying to get a GPS speed from my Glass (obviously the GPS signal would be coming through the phone). Using the following code, I was able to get location data from the network, but the speed always prints as 0.0. Using the GPS, I get an error that I've provided "an illegal argument" on the last line of the code below. What is the best way to get an accurate and consistent speed reading? Thank you in advance!

```
  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            location.getLatitude();

            System.out.println("Location changed. Speed is: " + location.getSpeed() + " Lat: " + location.getLatitude() + " Lon: " + location.getLongitude());
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                                    Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

    };


    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0,0, locationListener);
```

Comment: Never mind, figured out that if you use "remote_gps" instead of LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER on the last line it'll work.

Comment: You may be restricting yourself if you only use remote_gps, see "answer" below.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/location-sensors/index

From that Glass reference 
Warning: Do not use the LocationManager.getBestProvider() method or the constants GPS_PROVIDER or NETWORK_PROVIDER to listen for location updates. Glass uses a dynamic set of providers and listening only to a single provider may cause your application to miss location updates.

The Glass article suggests that you use a "criteria"-based location reference.